# Не могу разместить компонент регистрации

Tags: битрикс

Хочу разместить на странице компонент регистрации,но почему то появляется авторизация,не пойму что за прикол
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

По указанной Вами информации сказать что-то конкретное невозможно. Могу предположить, что в самом Битриксе отключена возможность самостоятельной регистрации пользователя

посмотрите в настройках сайта

```
Настройки - Настройки модулей - Главный модуль - 
вкладка "Авторизация" - блок "Регистрация новых пользователей" - 
чекбокс "Позволять ли пользователям регистрироваться самостоятельно?" 
(галочка должна быть установлена)
```

[image: скрин]